# How to use getopts with unix shell functions?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, getopts

The getopts command doesn't seem to work in a function. Maybe I did something wrong. The code below is what I have now. it is working if I put the whole while loop outside function. I am wondering if there is a way to make getopts work with functions ? I am new to the shell script. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
getOptions()
{
    while getopts :al:f:vd opt; do
            case "$opt" in
                    l) logFile = $OPTARG ;;
                    f) fileTable = $OPTARG ;;
                    v) verbose = 1 ;;
                    d) set -x ;;
                    a) echo "a";;
                    \?) echo "Invalid option: -$opt";;
            esac
    done
    shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One reason might be your usage of things like `logFile = $OPTARG` when you shouldn't have any spaces there (it should read `logFile=$OPTARG`).

Another reason is the fact that $1, $2, etc. are all referring to the function's arguments, not the shell script's arguments. Since the shell works that way, and getopts uses $1, $2, etc., you're using the function's arguments with getopts, not the script's arguments. In other words, confining your option processing to a shell function is not a good idea.

Comment: +1; I guess it's fine to use a function if you invoke it with `getOptions "$@"` to pass the _script's_ arguments through.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much! I always forget not to put spaces in between ...